# jersey client syntactically incorrect request error

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I have been trying jersey client to consume my jax-rs web service from another web service and i have been getting this 400 bad request error whenever i sent a post request from postman. I have configured jersey client to use message body-reader and writer that i have implemented myself using Gson. here is the code that calls another web service

```
 ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
         config.register(GsonWriter.class);
            config.register(GsonReader.class);

        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
        WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://localhost:8080/MessageBucket/MsgBucket/Api/bucket/msg");
        //WebTarget msgserviceWebTarget = webTarget.path("bucket/msg");
        System.out.println(webTarget.getUri());
        Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        Response response = invocationBuilder.post(Entity.entity(msg, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        String bresponse = response.readEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println("after request");

        return bresponse;
```

the msg object i am getting passed in as the parameter to the resource method of my other web service.

the error i get is:The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

Comment: turns out i had httpHeaders.get("Content-Type").add("charset=UTF-8"); line in my gson providers writeTo method.Once i commented it out the code works like a charm can somenone explain what this does and why code worked after its removal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out i had httpHeaders.get("Content-Type").add("charset=UTF-8"); line in my gson providers writeTo method.Once i commented it out the code works like a charm.